# How to cipher a specifc field inside soap request using CXF and X.509

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I'm building a cliente SOAP WS using CXF, and i have a problem, I need encrypt only one field in a request operation. I have done some tests
 using SOAPUI,  I loaded X.509 certificate and create a outgoing WS-Security configuration and select a specific field to cipher and WS call is ok . but using CXF, i dont know how to implements . I read some articles about topic , and using xml CXF configuration, but i have not found how to encrypt a specific field for SOAP request . For example i need encrypt request as the following:

```html
<soapenv:Body>
  <v2:ExampleRequest>
     <v2:field1>1909</v2:field1>
     <v2:field2>TEST</v2:field2>
     <v2:field3>22</v2:field3>
     <v2:field4><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-B26971BCECBE85FCAB14666299360062" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-B26971BCECBE85FCAB14666299359531"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>1eEPbo5tRbf+c+A7eNJOONL+amAA/To87XAa6nCsM6M=</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></v2: field4>
  </v2: ExampleRequest >
</soapenv:Body>
```

Some suggestions or opinions , I think it could be used a interceptor , but with interceptor only could be encrypted  value field without namespaces used in raw SOAP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CXF you use WSS4J for encryption. For clients you would use the WSS4JOutInterceptor. Examples how to use this are to be found [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html).

To specify which part of the message should be encrypted there is a property [WsHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_PARTS](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/ConfigurationConstants.html#ENCRYPTION_PARTS). Here is a short excerpt from the JavaDoc:

> Parameter to define which parts of the request shall be encrypted.
>
> The value of this parameter is a list of semi-colon separated element
>   names that identify the elements to encrypt. An encryption mode
>   specifier and a namespace identification, each inside a pair of curly
>   brackets, may preceed each element name.
>
> The encryption mode specifier is either {Content} or {Element}. Please
>   refer to the W3C XML Encryption specification about the differences
>   between Element and Content encryption. The encryption mode defaults
>   to Content if it is omitted. Example of a list:
>
> <parameter name="encryptionParts"
>   value="{Content}{http://example.org/paymentv2}CreditCard;
>                {Element}{}UserName" />

If you use javabased configuration it would be

```
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_PARTS, "{Content}{http://example.org/paymentv2}CreditCard;{Element}{}UserName");
```

Comment: What if you want to encrypt a child element like CreditCard.Name?